# Stacked icons on new top bar?

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, mobile-web

[image]

Look at the rightmost of the image. The MSO icon and the grayscale SE icon gets stacked up.

Google Chrome 63.0.3239.111 (from Play Store), Android 7.1.1.

Comment: No repro on all other sites so I came here.

Comment: Which device (this likely depends on screen resolution / density)? Probably related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306117/misalignment-in-top-bar-on-mobile-web-on-sites-with-long-names

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for your attention but I intentionally avoided posting this on MSE because MSO is the only place I can see it.

Comment: Well, website is called **stack**overflow, hence it inspires new icons design.

Comment: @Kaiido According to [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306123/350567), it's retracted now.

Comment: Does it stay this way for you or only show up like this for a short time? Typically the design loads some of the icons and allots space for those icons much later than most of the topbar.

Comment: @ʜᴏᴛsʟᴏᴡᴎᴇss In fact it's even called stack**over**flow. So if the visual flow is harmed by adding the stacking, then oh well, the stacking is more important.

Comment: You'll also note that it's the overflow (i.e. stuff that doesn't fit in the visible area) which is being stacked. I've never heard of CSS having an `overflow: stack;` property however.